# qgis2web does not display popup field

Tags: qgis2web

I'm using qgis2web plugin to create a simple web map. I have a huge attribute table and I would like to see some of fields from attribute table in web popup filed.

When I set popup fields and export map, all popups are same and show a value 1. How can I fixed that problem?

[image]

Also, in QGIS I set those points as triangle (not circles) but in web all of them are circles, plugin does not recognize point style?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: Do you need all of the fields in the popup? If not, set those you don't need to use 'Hidden' edit widgets in QGIS. See if that helps. And no, simple markers are always exported as circles. If you specify an SVG marker, that should work.